# global variable not recognized; says its local variable

Tags: python, variables, pysimplegui

Its not recognizing the global variable. I experienced this issue before and thought the global variable would prevent the error but no matter what i try it always returns this: local variable 'P1o' referenced before assignment

```
 #import pwinput
import PySimpleGUI as sg
P1o = ("")
P2o = ("")
MAX_ROWS = MAX_COL = 10
 def Battleship1():
    layout = [
                [sg.Text('Player1 please enter your ship positions'), sg.InputText('', size=(10,1), key='input_\P1o')],
                [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
                          ]
    window = sg.Window('player1 values', layout)
   
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        elif event == 'Submit':
            
            P1o = P1o.append(int(values['input_\P1o']))
            window.close()
        elif event == 'cancel':
            window.close()
            break
    layout = [
                [sg.Text('Player2 please enter your ship positions'), sg.InputText('', size=(10,1), key='input_\P2o')],
                [sg.Submit(), sg.Cancel()]
                          ]
    window = sg.Window('player2 values', layout)
    
    while True:
        event, values = window.read() 
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        if event == 'Submit':
            P1o = P1o.append(int(values['input_\P1o']))
            turn()
            turn_()
        if event == 'cancel':
            window.close()
            break

   """ i set up the multiplayer function"""
layout = [  [sg.Text("Welcome to battleship!!\nObject of the game is to sink all five of your enemy's ships!!!\nlabel your ship positions with a number (0-9)\n and another number (0-9)\n and separate each position with spaces e.g 1,2 2,3 3,4")],
            [sg.Button('Single Player'), sg.Button('Multiplayer')] ]
window = sg.Window('Menu', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == 'Multiplayer':
        window.close()
        Battleship1()
        break
```

Comment: Additionally: `P1o = P1o.append(int(values['input_\P1o']))` makes no sense when `P1o` is a string. And if you make `P1o` a list this still doesn't make sense, because `append` always returns `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `P1o` and `P2o` as your `local` variables, as they are only needed in your `battleship` function.

You can use them as your `global` or as your `local` variables. I'll leave the choice to you.

CASE 1: Using it as `local` variable:

```py
def Battleship1():
    P1o = ""
    P2o = ""
```

Here, it just creates two `local` variables for the function and would prevent the referenced before assignment error.

CASE 2: Using it as `global` variable:

```py
def Battleship1():
    global P1o, P2o
```

`global` keyword is used to reference the `globals()` dictionary where all the `global` variables are mentioned. So, it would tell the function that `P1o` and `P2o` is a `global` variable.